# Что это за шаблонизатор?

Tags: шаблонизаторы

Всем привет!

Попросили подправить один проект, у которого в моделях используется шаблонизатор. 
Подскажите, что это за шаблонизатор и если можно ссылку на его документацию.

Примеры:

[% USE Util %]

[% title | html _ c.app.conf.var.local %]

[% IF meta != '' -%]... [% END -%]

Comment: Это может быть любой шаблонизатор в зависимости от языка. Кроме того это может быть самописный. А что конкретно используется - можно а) посмотреть в самом проекте подключенные модули б) не страдать ерундой и спросить у заказчика

Comment: Заказчик не в курсе таких вещей, говорит надо связываться с программистом который раньше вел проект. Ладно, спасибо, буду ковыряться. Думал может кто навскидку сразу узнает и скажет мол да это то-то и то-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это Template Toolkit шаблонизатор на perl: http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html

Comment: Да, спасибо! Очень похоже что это именно он.

PS. Накоплю 15 баллов, отмечу ответ. :)